# No Reverse Match at /

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

my template:

```
<form action="{% url 'student:filter' %}" method='get'>
 <select>   
  <option value="00">----</option>
  <option value="01">Jan</option>
  <option value="02">Feb</option>
  <option value="03">Mar</option>
  <option value="04">Apr</option>
  <option value="05">May</option>
  <option value="06">Jun</option>
  <option value="07">Jul</option>
  <option value="08">Aug</option>
  <option value="09">Sept</option>
  <option value="10">Oct</option>
  <option value="11">Nov</option>
  <option value="12">Dec</option>
</select>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def filter(request, value):
    value = request.GET['value']
    att = Attendancename.objects.filter(date__hours=int(value))
    return render(request, 'listfilter.html', {'attend': att})
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^filter/(?P<value>\d+)$', views.filter, name = 'filter'),
```

What I want is to select a particular month from above html drop down, and its corresponding value needs to be passed in my views.py through url's argument, which then used in a look-up query.

But things are not working as I want. I'm doing something wrong with my templates, I don't know exactly how to trigger action corresponding to selected value in drop down.

Please! Can anybody tell me how to make it correct?

Thanks! in advance....

Comment: How you plan to submit the form ?

Comment: I plan to use the selected drop-down item value in the lookup query in my views.py file...

Comment: Django url patterns do not match against query strings

Answer (score 1):

Don't try and pass this data in the slug. In this case use the query string, which will be appended automatically by the browser for a GET.

```
<form action="{% url 'student:filter' %}" method='get'>
 <select name="filter">
  ...


def filter(request):
    value = request.GET['value']


url(r'^filter/$', views.filter, name = 'filter'),
```